# Проблема с видимостью sox в среде PyCharm

Tags: pycharm

Сделал установку sox согласно документации по установке
On Linux

```
# optional - if you want support for mp3, flac and ogg files
$ apt-get install libsox-fmt-all
# install the sox command line tool
$ apt-get install sox
# install pysox
$ pip install sox
```

Успешно установлен.
В программе в среде PyCharm
ругается на  sox  в строке

```
import sox
```

Инсталлирую прямо из среды PyCharm. Получаю что успешно установлен. Но ошибка остается.
Захожу в настройки, смотрю в настройках в окружении, sox есть.

В поисковике не нашел ответа. Но думаю проблема не редкая.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел причину. В настройках использовал Python 3.9 от Anaconda. Чтобы пакеты были видны, которые установлены через обычную настройку, надо выбирать "зеленое кольцо" использовать менеджер анаконды. Есть выбор, либо отказаться от выбора интерпретатора питона от анаконды и инсталлировать пакеты как обычно, либо использовать менеджер от анаконды в настройке интерпретатора.